# Elasticsearch aggregation only on specific entries in an array

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm new to Elasticsearch and can't figure out how to solve the following problem.
The easiest way to explain my problem is to show you an example.

The following array "listing" is part of all my files in Elasticsearch, but the entries vary, so the "person" with the "id" 42, might be in 50% of my files. What I'm trying to do is to get the average "ranking.position.standard" of all the persons with id 42 in all my files in Elasticsearch.

```
{
"listing": [
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 42
        },
        "ranking": {
            "position": {
                "standard": 2
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 55
        },
        "ranking": {
            "position": {
                "standard": 7
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have tried all kinds of filtering. All I have achieved so far, was to get the whole file back, if the "listing" array had an entry with the "id" 42.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do you store listings as an `object` or `nested` data type? I don't think it's going to work if it's an `object`, so try the following example:

```js
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "listing": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /test/aa/1
{
  "listing": [
    {
      "person": {
        "id": 42
      },
      "ranking": {
        "position": {
          "standard": 2
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "id": 55
      },
      "ranking": {
        "position": {
          "standard": 7
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

PUT /test/aa/2
{
  "listing": [
    {
      "person": {
        "id": 42
      },
      "ranking": {
        "position": {
          "standard": 5
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "id": 55
      },
      "ranking": {
        "position": {
          "standard": 6
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}  

GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nest": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "listing"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "persons": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "listing.person.id",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_standard": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "listing.ranking.position.standard"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This has brought me the following result:

```json
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "nest": {
      "doc_count": 4,
      "persons": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 42,
            "doc_count": 2,
            "avg_standard": {
              "value": 3.5
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 55,
            "doc_count": 2,
            "avg_standard": {
              "value": 6.5
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It does seem correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The default mapping generated:
"listing": {
            "properties": {...}
}
but, how did you query it, to get exactly that result?

Comment: @McClane if it worked for you, check this as accepted ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @McClane I missed your edit. Query is simple, I did not filter anything, just aggregated data, first of all I had to use nested aggregation to access nested data structures (they're being normally stored as separate docs), then I did a terms aggregation to get all unique `person.id` values and then I did yet another aggregation for each `terms` bucket to get average standard. :) so it was `nested` -> `terms` -> `avg`. Three levels of aggregations.